# Slow GridView question

Tags: asp.net

I have a GridView with textboxes and CompareValidators in its cells. The GridView has 40 columns and is very slow. I wonder if it is possible to avoid compare validators in every cell. Is it possible to have one instance   of a particular validator for e.g. the whole column?

Thanks.

Comment: This is one of those situations where the problems might be driven by design decisions. You might want to ask yourself if an editable GridView with 40 columns is the best design choice. Wouldn't it make more sense to display 5 columns in the GridView and offer access to all of the fields through another mechanism like a modal pop-up or a details view on another page?

Comment: Your question is a little unclear.  When you say the "GridView...is very slow", what exactly do you mean?  It seems like you are saying the browser becomes unresponsive when you try to enter data into a row in edit mode.  Is that right?  You also imply that you know the performance problem is actually because of the `CompareValidator` controls.  Have you removed the `CompareValidator`s to see if the performance improves?

Comment: @Rick Liddle Rick, I agree with you, but the user wants the page to look and act like Excel spreadsheet.

Comment: @pseudocoder When I say "GridView... is very slow", I mean that it takes long time to load the page with the GridView. All records are editable. I removed validators, and it became twice faster.

Comment: @dpreznik How many rows does the GridView typically have, and is a row always in edit mode when you get the slowness?

Comment: @pseudocoder All rows are in Edit mode, as the GridView should look and act like Excel spreadsheet. It is 100 rows per page.